# how to generate and get the coupon code?

Tags: collection, magento-1, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon

```
    $generator = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon_massgenerator');
    $data = array(
        'uses_per_customer' => 1,
        'uses_per_coupon'   => 1,
        'qty'               => 1,  //number of coupons to generate
        'length'            => 16, //length of coupon string
        'to_date'           => date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 month",  time())), //ending date of generated promo
        'prefix'            => 'rev',
        'suffix'            => 'tf',
        'dash'              => 5,
        /**
         * Possible values include:
         * Mage_SalesRule_Helper_Coupon::COUPON_FORMAT_ALPHANUMERIC
         * Mage_SalesRule_Helper_Coupon::COUPON_FORMAT_ALPHABETICAL
         * Mage_SalesRule_Helper_Coupon::COUPON_FORMAT_NUMERIC
         */
        'format'          => Mage_SalesRule_Helper_Coupon::COUPON_FORMAT_ALPHANUMERIC,
        'rule_id'         => 1 //the id of the rule you will use as a template
    );
    $generator->validateData($data);
    $generator->setData($data);
    $generator->generatePool();

    $salesRule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($data['rule_id']);
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/coupon_collection')
                ->addRuleToFilter($salesRule)
                ->addGeneratedCouponsFilter();
```

I have this method to generate coupon code but **how can I get a coupon code**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the last generated coupon code you will have to modify your collection like this:

```
$couponCode = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/coupon_collection')
                ->addRuleToFilter($salesRule)
                ->addGeneratedCouponsFilter()
                ->getLastItem()
                ->getData('code');
```

The two lines I've added get the last item and retrieve the corresponding code.

Comment: actually these two things,  1.generation 2.retreive are happening at two different times .will it be correct for high traffic site.  because we are getting last generated coupon code . but if a request comes between the gap will it fail. normally will it happen or am I thinking wrong

Comment: @HaimanoHellomano what do you mean ?

Comment: @HaimanoHellomano your idea is totally right. This will fail if a request happens in between. However Magento does not provide any other way to do that. What you will have to do is to retrieve the code right after the generation (using my code), store it somewhere and do whatever you want with it after.